# EHX LPB1 circuit not working

Tags: audio, dc, soldering, potentiometer, guitar-pedal

I am very new to making circuits and have tried to make an EHX LPB1 circuit:
[image]

When powered and plugged in, the 9v battery overheats and all I can hear in my amplifier is static noises and no output. ive tested connections and everything seems connected the potentiometer ranges a little with the multimeter when powered. My work is quite messy, also I couldn't buy any 830k resistors so i put 8 100k's and 3 10k's in series:
[image]
[image]
Please could you suggest anything I could do to the current circuit to repair it or do in future when I make another attempt. If you'd rather contact me using another media I have an email: squifflangdown@gmail.com

Thanks for any help. Also not sure if we're allowed to just post our attempts and ask for help but im not sure where else I can ask for help

Comment: You need to break (cut) the copper strips on the board where you don't want connections.

Comment: Oh. Does that mean everything on each line is connected?

Comment: The copper strips run the full length of the board - anything you connect to a strip anywhere is connected to anything else on that strip, unless you break the strip.  There is a suitable tool available to "drill out" around a hole, to break the connection, but I've used a small drill bit turned by hand, or a sharp knife.

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't know that. I thought it was flux. Thanks a lot for the help. I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that everything is connected to everything!
Those lines along the bottom of the perfboard are copper, and anything soldered into the same line will be connected to each other. For example, your 8x100k resistors are all connected in parallel in that configuration - not series.

And the huge blue capacitor in the bottom right is not doing anything because the legs are both soldered into the same track, so any current is just going to ignore it.

The reason your battery is overheating is because none of your components are acting like a 'load' - that is, your battery's current is just running straight back into itself without being used to power anything - you are **shorting** it.

The website [DIY stompboxes](https://www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/) is a useful resource for getting started with building pedals.